# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException while added context:component-scan

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Here is my spring.xml,along with the maven dependency and package name:

[Package name,spring.xml,Maven dependency](https://plus.google.com/102593617594493694546/posts/XEpeXLsuPpn?pid=6139890278824479570&oid=102593617594493694546)

i could not provide the spring.xml as code because the namespace converted into link and i cannot post more than 2 link because of reputation.

lower part of spring.xml

```
<bean id="user" class="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.UserDetails"
    autowire="byName">

    <property name="adminName" value="Root"></property>
    <property name="name" value="Sparsh"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="officeAddress" class="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.Address">
    <property name="roomNumber" value="${roomNumber}"></property>
    <property name="streetName" value="office"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="homeAddress" class="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.Address">
    <property name="roomNumber" value="1"></property>
    <property name="streetName" value="home"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>
                message
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean
    class="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.DisplayBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean class="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.DisplayBeanFactory" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="variable.properties" />
</bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey" />
```

Everything was great but when i add

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey" />
```

facing error as :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.HelloWorldREST.<clinit>(HelloWorldREST.java:122)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor._construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:245)
at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor.construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:233)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.PerRequestFactory$PerRequest._getInstance(PerRequestFactory.java:182)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.PerRequestFactory$AbstractPerRequest.getInstance(PerRequestFactory.java:144)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationContext.getResource(WebApplicationContext.java:239)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

HelloWorldRest.java

```
package com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldREST {

    @GET
    @Path("/signin/")
    public Response responseMsg(@QueryParam("email") String email,
            @QueryParam("pass") String pass) {

        Session session = factory.openSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Long password = (Long) session.createQuery(
                "select count(*) from UserDetails where EmailID = '" + email
                        + "'and password = '" + pass + "'").uniqueResult();
        System.out.println(password);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        if (password > 0)
            return Response.status(200).entity("success").build();
        else
            return null;

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/signup/")
    public Response responseMsg(@QueryParam("name") String name,
            @DefaultValue("Nothing to say") @QueryParam("email") String email,
            @QueryParam("date") String date, @QueryParam("pass") String pass) {

        Session session = factory.openSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        UserDetails user = (UserDetails) context.getBean("user");

        user.setEmailID(email);
        if (name.length() != 0)
            user.setName(name);
        user.setDate(date);
        user.setPass(pass);
        session.save(user);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        return Response.status(200).entity("success").build();

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/submit/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONObject submitValue(@QueryParam("start") int start,
            @QueryParam("limit") int limit, @QueryParam("page") int page) {

        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query qry = session.createQuery("from UserDetails");

        qry.setFirstResult(start);
        qry.setMaxResults(limit);

        List<UserDetails> userObject = (List<UserDetails>) qry.list();

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();

        jObject.put("result", userObject);
        jObject.put("success", true);
        Long count = (Long) session.createQuery(
                "select count(*) from UserDetails").uniqueResult();
        jObject.put("totalcount", count);

        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        return jObject;

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/delete/")
    public Response hqlTruncate() {
        String hql = String.format("delete from UserDetails");
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        return Response.status(200).entity("success").build();
    }

    static AbstractApplicationContext context;
    static SessionFactory factory = null;
    static {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.configure();
        ServiceRegistryBuilder srBuilder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
        srBuilder.applySettings(config.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = srBuilder.buildServiceRegistry();
        factory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        System.out.println(context.getMessage("greeting", null,
                "default message", null));
        context.registerShutdownHook();

    }
}
```

Comment: Show `HelloWorldREST` please.

Comment: Edited the post with HelloWorldREST.java

Comment: in eclipse it is showing line number 122 is 

factory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);